# Why are the parameters of the ASMX Proxy Methods capsulated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, wsdl

I am adding a Service Reference to a Third-Party-ASMX Webservice in my VS2015 or VS2017 Project (Net 4.6.1).

I do this with the normal Userinterface in Visual Studio (Rightclick --> Add new Service Reference). I use the default settings and everything seems to work except that i am not happy with the generated classes.

According to the WSDL i am expecting to use the methods like this:

```
ServiceSoapClient ssc = new ServiceSoapClient(); 
object response = ssc.getEmployees("xxx", "yyy", "zzz");
```

But what i get is classes that i have to use like this:

```
ServiceSoapClient ssc = new ServiceSoapClient(); 
getEmployeesResponse response = ssc.getEmployees(
        new getEmployeesRequest
        {
            Body = new getEmployeesRequestBody { Division = "xxx", Username = "yyy", Password = "zzz" }
        });
```

Every Method needs one Request-Parameter, which itself has a Body-Element. The Body-Element has all the necessary Parameters.

The Method is defined like that when opened in the browser:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getEmployees xmlns="xxx">
      <division>string</division>
      <Username>string</Username>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </getEmployees>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

That is the information for this Method in the WSDL:

```
<s:element name="getEmployees">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="division" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Username" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="getEmployeesResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="getEmployeesResult" type="tns:XMLResponse"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>

<wsdl:operation name="getEmployees">
<wsdl:input message="tns:getEmployeesSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:getEmployeesSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:operation name="getEmployees">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://xxx/getEmployees" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

**Why do i not get a method with the three parameters of type string? Am i even able to control this on client-side or is there a common mistake?**

When i provide the Webservices by myself or use other services i never had this problem before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. In the settings of the "Service Reference" you have to activate "Generate assynchronous operations".

[image]